# DSM-5 Assessments for App (electronic) use

Tags: measurement, computational-modeling, psychiatry, software, dsm

I'm a budding entrepreneur building an app in the health and wellness space. As a part of the onboarding and user journey experience, I'm thinking of incorporating all [DSM-5 assessments](https://www.psychiatry.org/psychiatrists/practice/dsm/educational-resources/assessment-measures) in my app, including the ones that are not owned by APPA (PROMIS, WHO, etc.). Now  on the [APPA Permissions](https://webapps.psychiatry.org/RequestForm/) page, it states that the *Use of material in applications for mobile devices such as iPad, iPod, iPhone, Android, BlackBerry, and any other devices"* is NOT granted. Does that mean I cannot use these assessments at all? Or are they referring to the [DSM-5 manual](https://www.appi.org/Diagnostic_and_Statistical_Manual_of_Mental_Disorders_DSM-5_Fifth_Edition) when they say "material" and I can still use the assessments.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. I would say that the restriction can only be applied to materials the APA produced (e.g. Level 1 Cross-Cutting Symptom Measures and others adapted by APA). Those produced by other organisations would need permission from them. Having said that, this is a legal issue which you would need to check with a lawyer or someone else proficient in the relevant laws. Maybe this question should be asked at [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Legal advice is off-topic at law.SE, as it is here.  Perhaps this question could be restructured in some way as to focus on how certain legal terms are to be interpreted, and maybe then it could be on-topic at law.SE.  I recommend contacting the APA directly for clarification on their terms.